# Como bloquear caracteres aleatórios no Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário e gostaria de remover os caracteres aleatórios.
Tipo:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccc
20323092093023029302
weweiowoeiow
o392039209320939
```

Descrição: Não apenas esses, gostaria de deixar o formulário um pouco seguro. Impedir que usuário crie coisas assim. O script abaixo faz um random "aleatoriedade" queria usar isso para previnir esse acontecimento....

```
function generateRandomNumber(){
    "use strict";

    // se o browser tiver suporte à getRandomValues()
    if (Uint32Array && window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) { 
        var numbers = new Uint32Array(1);
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(numbers);
        return numbers[0] * Math.pow(2,-32);

    // caso não tenha, é utilizado Math.random
    } else {
        return Math.random();
    }
}

function shuffle(string) {
    "use strict";
    var parts = string.split('');

    for (var i = parts.length; i > 0;) {
        var random = parseInt(generateRandomNumber() * i); // aqui é chamada a função que gera o número aleatório
        var temp = parts[--i];
        parts[i] = parts[random];
        parts[random] = temp;
    }

    return parts.join('');
}
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que está querendo fazer e muito menos porque os caracteres citados foram considerados "aleatórios". Poderia elaborar um [mcve] para o seu problema?

Comment: Poderia definir o que são caracteres aleatórios?

Comment: Seria isso "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" "sdskjksdkjsjdk" "dksjkjjk23jk23kj" Rs...

Comment: Não deu pra entender. Vc quer impedir "números aleatórios" no seu formulário e possui uma função que "gera" tais números? Pra que serve a função?

Comment: Rs.... é um exemplo... Eu quero impedir "números aleatórios"... E usei esse exemplo, queria entender como funciona... para impedir isso.

Comment: Se você precisa validar dados fornecidos por usuário, dê uma lida em expressões regulares e aplicação de máscaras, só pra começar. Há vasto material sobre este conteúdo na internet (lidar com dados de usuário - user input).

Comment: okay ;D vocês são fera e sempre que posso incluo todos os nomes nos meus 'programas'

Comment: Não tem como prever o que um usuário pode digitar pra burlar um input, eu mesmo quando não há mascaras pra telefone eu preencho "SemTelefone", "SemEmail".

Comment: Tens razão ;D cara

Comment: Pessoal, com a resposta! Posso criar um expressão regular com certos padrões e assim bloquear ou impedir que ela seja feita no input? O exemplo abaixo, o amigo citou que é possível criar um dicionário e impedir essas palavras! Agora, penso será que poderia utilizar as expressões regulares para fazer um padrão e assim impedir ou bloquear via input? Exemplo,  o padrão 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' .... a expressão poderia ser 'a'(sequencia).  Se 'a-z tiver uma sequencia sem espaço' =  bloquear, impedir.

Comment: Se a-z tiver aleatoriedade... Exemplo, 'askdjskdksjdkjskdjsdkjweowieoweiwoieoweowie' =  bloquear, impedir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara fiz algo que pode te ajudar, a ideia é vc colocar dentro do array palavras que sao banidas e ai vc consegue controlar o que o usuario nao pode enviar

```js
var lista_palavras_banidas = [
"aaaaaaa", "jsdkjfids", "jijaswwww", "bebbbebeb"
];

function verifica(){
  var b = false;
  var a = document.getElementById("inputA").value;
  for (let index = 0; index < lista_palavras_banidas.length; index++) {
    if(lista_palavras_banidas[index] === a ){
      b = true;
      break;
    };

  }
  console.log(b);
  if(b){
    inputInvalid();
  }
}

function inputInvalid(){
document.getElementById("inputA").style.border = "2px solid red";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
  <form>
    <input id="inputA" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:verifica()" />
  </form>
 
  </body>
</html>
```